# I'm trying to return the complete sentence by searching with one word in pdf file with python but getting page number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, nlp, pypdf

**I'm trying to return the complete sentence by searching with one word in pdf file with python but getting page number**

For example there is a sentence  like

This person has done money laundering (This sentence comes under page 6).
I'm trying to fetch that particular sentence where the sentence contains word laundering.

The code is below :

```
import PyPDF2
import re

pattern = "laundering"
fileName = "result.pdf"

object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fileName)
numPages = object.getNumPages()

for i in range(0, numPages):
    pageObj = object.getPage(i)
    text = pageObj.extractText()
    text = text.lower()
   
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
        print(f'Page no: {i} | Match: {match}')
```

Output is :

```
Page no: 6 | Match: <re.Match object; span=(1688, 1698), match='laundering'>
Page no: 30 | Match: <re.Match object; span=(1452, 1462), match='laundering'>
Page no: 54 | Match: <re.Match object; span=(1690, 1700), match='laundering'>
Page no: 78 | Match: <re.Match object; span=(1652, 1662), match='laundering'>
Page no: 101 | Match: <re.Match object; span=(469, 479), match='laundering'>
Page no: 125 | Match: <re.Match object; span=(1657, 1667), match='laundering'>
```

I'm expecting like output :

```
'Complete sentence', page no 6
'Complete sentence', page no 30
''
''
'Complete sentence', page no 125
```

Comment: It looks like match.span contains a tuple of the start and end char positions of the word 'laundering'.  To fetch the sentence containing the word, you need to find the start and end of the sentence.  This would mean finding the previous sentence terminator and the following sentence terminator.  Note a sentence terminator can be a period, question mark, exclamation point, etc.

Comment: Worse than that. A period could be a number, a question mark a URL. PDF is not a word processing format. Unless the PDF is structured there is little chance of doing this correctly. Not to mention that the word could be learned and may not be in a singular PDF phrase.

Answer (score 0):

`re.finditer(pattern, text)` is returning an `iterator of Match object`. To access the actual text matched, you can use `match.group(0)` to return the entire match in `str` format.

As you want to extract the sentences and not simply your defined pattern you need to modify your regular expression to capture the words before and after it.

I would do as follows:

```
tx = '''This is a test1!
this is a test2.
test1.
This is a test3'''

import re
pattern = 'test1'
for m in re.finditer(f"([^!?.]*{pattern}.*[!?.])", tx):
    print(m.group(0))
```

output:

```
This is a test1!

test1.
```

This regex will capture all characters before and after your pattern that are not punctuation marks.